# Custom XCode Template?

Tags: iphone, xcode, templates, xcode-template

I would like to make my own iPhone Application Templates in XCode, based on a modified project from the Apple templates.

For example, I would like to take a View Based project, add an Image View and save that project as a template. Really, this is just an example.

Is this possible? How so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a full tutorial look at this: http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/cocoa-dev-design-your-own-xcode-project-templates.ars
And just make an Xcode project that is formatted the way you want it. In short just bring your new formatted Xcode project to here: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application

Answer (score 6):

thyrgle's answer may have been relevant in June of 2010 when everyone was using Xcode 3. But things have changed considerably in Xcode 4. Maybe try [this tutorial](http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/). Or even [this one](http://www.gandogames.com/2011/08/automating-xcode-4-template-generation/).

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as Question Follow Below Steps

Step 1:
Open finder, go to Applications and right click on Xcode to show package contents. Navigate to Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Application

Step 2:
There you can see folder with extension .xctemplate copy it.

Step 3:
Change the name of folder run Xcode you can see template of your name.

Step 4:
If you want to customise your template make changes in .plist file.